# open an URL upon my extension has been installed or uninstalled

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

As for open an URL upon my extension has been uninstalled, I found the easiest way to do is using `chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL`, **(1)** any other good ways?

As for open an URL upon my extension has been first time installed, I don't find something like `chrome.runtime.setInstallURL`, I implemented the feature with

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details){
    if (details.reason=="install"){chrome.tabs.create({ url: homePage});}
    })
```

I saw [AdBlock](https://adblockplus.org/en/) opens its options page upon first time installed, but it doesn't even used `chrome.runtime.onInstalled`, its source code is so much complicated , I cannot figure out how it implement the feature ,**(2)** how it do it ? any other ways to open an URL or its options page upon the extension has been first time installed?

**(3)** what are  the common ways to do something when an extension has been installed or uninstalled?

Answer (score 0):

[SetUninstallURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/setUninstallURL) seems to be specifically designed for your task, so it's certainly the right way.

Regarding the installation page, not sure how AdBlock does it, but if you have a persistent background page, one of the simpler ways would be to show the page on every launch if a certain `localStorage` key is not set.

```
// background.html startup, for example DOMContentLoaded handler

if ( !localStorage.getItem('intro_shown') ) {
 localStorage.setItem('intro_shown', true);
 showIntroPage();
}
```

Local storage of the extension's background page will be persistent, apart from several corner cases (incognito mode in FF, etc).

**Upd by Makyen**: 
[chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) seems to be a much better option specifically designed for extension storage needs. It could also be automatically synced with Chrome sync (using `chrome.storage.sync`)

Comment: While `localStorage` will work, using [`chrome.storage.local`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) (or `.sync` if you are synchronizing your settings) would be preferred in a Chrome extension.

Comment: @Makyen I found chrome.storage.sync is much better a choice

Comment: @Makyen Indeed, I forgot about that. It could be a better option.

Comment: @iMath, Which to use depends on your desire wrt. opening the URL when installed on another computer which is syncing with one where the extension is already installed. Use `.sync`, if you don't want to open the URL page in that situation. We don't have enough information about what you are using the URL for to make a judgment as to which is more reasonable. For the options page example, it would be very reasonable to not open the options page on a new machine if your extension is syncing the rest of the options and the user would not normally need to adjust options on a new machine.

Comment: @Makyen For the options page you mentioned in the case - would be much convenient  if {'intro_shown', false} was synced with chrome.storage.sync